# EditableGridView failure to plug in

Tags: yii, grid

I want to plug in the EditableGridView for a model in yii. 
I've followed the instructions to plugin from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/editablegridview)
I've just uploaded the php class source files into '/protected/extentions' folder and inserted into a view:

```
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CEditableGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'showQuickBar'=>'true',
    'quickCreateAction'=>'QuickCreate', // will be actionQuickCreate()
    'columns'=>array(
       'title',          // display the 'title' attribute
        array('header' => 'editMe', 'name' => 'editable_row', 'class' => 'CEditableColumn')
  ));
```

When i run it the 'Alias "zii.widgets.grid.CEditableGridView" is not valid' CException is on.
What's wrong? Do i need to add more into /congig/main.php as i did with x-editable 'EditableDetailView' to plug it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location where you put the extension is important to tell what you doing wrong.
I went to your reference http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/editablegridview. Actually it was wrong when provide the sample code with different alias with what tutorial was shown you

They told `"Extract both Classes to application/extensions/"` but in the sample code, it was using `zii.widgets.grid`, the extension inside Yii `framework` folder.

I assume you put your downloaded extension and your structure of folder as follow

```
your_app
!_protected
!_!_extensions
!_!_!_widgets
!_!_!_!_editableGrid <== folder contains extension files

Put them here
!_!_!_!_!_CEditableColumn.php
!_!_!_!_!_CEditableGridView.php
!_!_!_!_!_Relation.php
```

Then here we go

```
$this->widget('ext.widgets.editableGrid.CEditableGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'showQuickBar'=>'true',
    'quickCreateAction'=>'QuickCreate', // will be actionQuickCreate()
    'columns'=>array(
        'title',          // display the 'title' attribute
        array(
         'header' => 'editMe', 
         'name' => 'editable_row', 
         'class' => 'ext.widgets.editableGrid.CEditableColumn' // noted the modified alias here
        ))));
```